# Expandable language selection with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build an expandable language selection element with HTML and CSS. Here is what it looks like initially:

[image]

And here is what I want it to look like when you hover over:

[image]

My HTML:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 33px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: none;
}

.icon.active-icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="icon active-icon" src="./ua.svg" alt="" />
  <img class="icon" src="./ru.svg" alt="" />
  <img class="icon" src="./en.svg" alt="" />
</div>
```

For some reason `display` property does not get changed on `hover` and the elements that are displayed as `none` initially, do not appear.

Comment: You have a hidden element, and you want it so that when you hover *on that hidden element*, it reveals itself. How does that work?

Comment: There are 3 elements that have ```icon``` class, one of them has ```active-icon``` class and its ```display``` property is set to ```inline-block``` which makes it visible. Since it also has ```icon``` class I thought that making ```display: inline-block``` for all ```icon``` elements on hover would work

Comment: No. `.icon:hover` affects only that one specific hovered icon. It doesn't magically affect all `.icon`s - in fact that would be *highly* undesirable. Instead try `.wrapper:hover>.icon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are hovering the icon, it doesn't affect all the elements of `.icon` class, rather it only affects the hovered one. You can set the `:hover` on your `.wrapper` class and set `inline-block` for `.icon` on hovering wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 33px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: none;
}

.icon.active-icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper:hover .icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="icon active-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20/FF0000/000000?text=1" alt="" />
  <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20/00FF00/000000?text=2" alt="" />
  <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20/0000FF/0000000?text=3" alt="" />
</div>
```

For more in-depth knowledge about this:
[How to affect other elements when one element is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)